# Deduplicate N messages from RabbitMQ with same Time but different conflicting Action

Tags: python, data-structures, rabbitmq, message-queue

I have a RabbitMQ queue that receives buy/sell orders; However, we get multiple orders at the same time...

message 1

```
{
    "time": "2020-08-12T16:53:04Z",
    "order": "buy",
    "order_contract": 5,
    "ticker": "6E1!",
    "price": 1.1806,
    "market_position": "long", 
    "position_size": 15
}
```

message 2

```
{
    "time": "2020-08-12T16:53:04Z",
    "order": "sell",
    "order_contract": 5,
    "ticker": "6E1!",
    "price": 1.1804000000000001,
    "market_position": "short", 
    "position_size": -10
}
```

message 3

```
{
    "time": "2020-08-12T16:53:04Z",
    "order": "sell",
    "order_contract": 20,
    "ticker": "6E1!",
    "price": 1.1805,
    "market_position": "short", 
    "position_size": -5
}
```

We need to process all the messages from the Queue, but then only send one message to be executed for this timeslot. Which means we need to deduplicate and get the final message. We're only likely to only get 15 messages within the same time.

In this case, the message that should be executed after deduplication is

```
{
    "time": "2020-08-12T16:53:04Z",
    "order": "sell",
    "order_contract": 5,
    "ticker": "6E1!",
    "price": 1.1804000000000001,
    "market_position": "short", 
    "position_size": -10
}
```

Why? We had 2 (two) orders which say "sell" and the largest position size in that direction is -10.

Trying to figure out the algorithm that best processes the message from the queue and then only execute the message after deduplication. Since I don't know if another message will arrive; I need to execute the "winning" message after say 1 second.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I don't see how this relates to Python.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following [pattern](https://segment.com/blog/exactly-once-delivery/) which solved my solution. In their pattern, they use Kafka and RockDB to address deduplication plus a host of other benefits.